# Alpine Linux 3.4.6 x86 Standard qemu boot failed

Tags: kali-linux, virtualbox, qemu, alpine-linux

I've been following the direction on their [wiki](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Install_Alpine_in_Qemu).

However, I get the following:

> sudo qemu-system-i386 -cdrom ../alpine-3.4.6-x86.iso -hda alpine.qcow -boot d -net nic -net user -m 256 -localtime

But, the qemu window just stops after the message `boot:` forever.
Same even with their 'virt' image.

Tried the same with kali linux iso, and it works.

> sudo qemu-system-i386 -cdrom ../kali-linux-1.1.0a-i386-mini.iso -hda alpine.qcow -boot d -net nic -net user -m 256 -localtime
>   So its not related to my system config or qemu .

Same behaviour while booting both images with VirtualBox too.
Any workarounds?

Answer (score 0):

I've tested your iso with qemu version 2.8.0, and it boots without issue.
I added the switch -display curses:

```
 sudo qemu-system-i386 -cdrom ./alpine-3.4.6-x86.iso -hda alpine.qcow -boot d -net nic -net user -m 256 -localtime -display curses
```

Please check the integrity of the ISO to be sure that is not corrupted:

```
 $> wget https://mirror.de.leaseweb.net/alpine/v3.4/releases/x86/alpine-3.4.6-x86.iso.sha256
 $> wget https://mirror.de.leaseweb.net/alpine/v3.4/releases/x86/alpine-3.4.6-x86.iso
 $> sha256sum -c alpine-3.4.6-x86.iso.sha256
 alpine-3.4.6-x86.iso: OK
```